# Express route not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am fairly new to the concepts of express. Anyway, I am trying to build subroutes for a certain "plan" and do corresponding actions.

I start out on something like mypage.com/someroute/123321312

```
router.get('/:planId', function(req, res, next) {
  //a form is rendered and sent in responce to client
});
```

WORKS!

After filling out the form which was rendered:

```
<form id="bioData" method="post" action="confirm">
```

I submit the Form and it redirects me to mypage.com/someroute/123321312/confirm

FAILS! 404! The Url is as expected with the trailing `/confirm` route

I want to respond to the triggered request by handling the route on the serverside like so:

```
router.get('/:planId/confirm', function(req, res, next) {
  //a different page should be rendered
});
```

Why does react not map the request to this route?

It must be something obvious - if you need more code just ask! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your method is `post` but mapped as a `get`, change it!

```
router.post('/:planId/confirm', function(req, res, next) {
        ^^
```

Comment: AWWWWWWWW, I knew it must of been something obvious - *facepalm*... Ill mark it as correct as soon as I can :)